# R dplyr: Filter Not Working on Numeric Value

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to filter a dataframe using dplyr but my code is failing to filter a particular value.  The values are all numeric, and forcing numeric doesn't fix the issue.  However, if I alter my code to filter a value enclosed in quotes, the code works.  I don't know why filtering is failing.

I'm simplified the data below.  It is not so simple to change the code to filter within quotes, so I am looking for an explanation on how to alter the column data so that a numeric value can be filtered successfully.

Thanks!

| Unique_ID | Minutes | AvgOD_TechReps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JVY302_SDC_Rep3 | 240 | 0.257 |
| JVY302_SDC_Rep3 | 250 | 0.269 |

I have simplified th

```
#Confirm column contains numeric values
> str(df$Minutes)
 num [1:2] 240 250

#Filter using values enclosed in quotes works
df2 <- df %>%
  dplyr::filter(Minutes == "240" | Minutes == "250") 

> df2
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Unique_ID       Minutes AvgOD_TechReps
  <chr>             <dbl>          <dbl>
1 JVY302_SDC_Rep3     240          0.265
2 JVY302_SDC_Rep3     250          0.276

#Filter using numeric values fails for the 250 value
df3 <- df %>%
  dplyr::filter(Minutes == 240 | Minutes == 250) 

> df3
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  Unique_ID       Minutes AvgOD_TechReps
  <chr>             <dbl>          <dbl>
1 JVY302_SDC_Rep3     240          0.265

#Forcing the column to be number does not solve the problem
df4 <- df %>%
  dplyr::mutate_at("Minutes", as.numeric) %>%
  dplyr::filter(Minutes == 240 | Minutes == 250)

> df4
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  Unique_ID       Minutes AvgOD_TechReps
  <chr>             <dbl>          <dbl>
1 JVY302_SDC_Rep3     240          0.265
```

Comment: Please check if there is precision involved as it is double

Comment: Maybe try `dplyr::mutate_at("Minutes", as.integer)` (instead of `as.numeric`)cto convert to integer to solve precision issues

Comment: Gregor this worked - if you post as an answer I can give you credit and signal that the thread is closed.  I didn't expect precision issues, because the values in that column are calculated that same way, but alas, that was the issue.

Comment: I just marked as duplicate of the R-FAQ we have for this issue.